# breaking the else-if connection? (java)

Tags: java, if-statement

i have the following code (its content doesn't matter much though):

```
if (row+1>0 && row+1<mat.length) //valid move down
    if (nextVal==mat[row+1][clmn])
        return isPath (mat, val+1, row+1, clmn);

    if (row-1>0 && row-1<mat.length) //valid move up
        if (nextVal==mat[row-1][clmn])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row-1, clmn);

    if (clmn+1>0 && clmn+1<mat.length) //valid move right
        if (nextVal==mat[row][clmn+1])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn+1);

    if (clmn-1>0 && clmn-1<mat.length) //valid move left
        if (nextVal==mat[row][clmn-1])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn-1);
!!!!    else return false;
else return false;
```

Un order to be able to use else statement in regard to **all** ifs, i had to add the marked (!!!!) line.

My question is: Is there a way to remove that line and not have the else statement "lock" into the same block as the last if?

Comment: **Yes**. Just add a `return false;` and remove both `else`(s). The only way you would reach that, is if all of the other `return` statements aren't met.

Comment: I recommend always using curly brackets around if-statements (even if they're just one line) to help visually sort out your logic :)

Comment: you also can add the pairs of if's together since you check if this is true and if this true return isPath for all. just use a single if with && for the if under it

Comment: That's a [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else). Just use `{}`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch ahh youre right. did not even think about thinking about it :P

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz that ineed works. for some reason it didn't when i first wrote it. that's why i broke it down to 2 nested ifs

Comment: @james it's good to break it down into a bunch of pieces first and then once you have a working program you can go back refactor it.

Comment: add only return false at the end and remove last two else

Comment: Use curly brackets!  Always use curly brackets for control statements (like `if`, `while`, `try`) even when they're not needed.  It avoids a lot of common mistakes, especially when modifying code later.  Every professional programmer I've worked with since the 70's follows this practice.  Every serious coding standard recommends it.

Comment: Unrelated, but I think `row+1>0` should be `row+1>=0`, and analogeously for the other `>0` checks, and the checks for `clmn` might fail if the matrix is not square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change to your code to make it work is this:

```
    if (row+1>0 && row+1<mat.length) //valid move down
        if (nextVal==mat[row+1][clmn])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row+1, clmn);

    if (row-1>0 && row-1<mat.length) //valid move up
        if (nextVal==mat[row-1][clmn])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row-1, clmn);

    if (clmn+1>0 && clmn+1<mat.length) //valid move right
        if (nextVal==mat[row][clmn+1])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn+1);

    if (clmn-1>0 && clmn-1<mat.length) //valid move left
        if (nextVal==mat[row][clmn-1])
            return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn-1);

    return false;
```

I hope this clarifies why your logic doesn't work: you were returning false only when `(nextVal==mat[row][clmn-1])` is true and `(nextVal==mat[row][clmn-1])` is false, and not if any of the other cases fail.  Note that even your "fixed" code isn't correct for all cases, assuming you want to return false if none of the returns above are taken.

But **don't code it like this!** Use curly braces, always!

Also, using "&&" rather than a nested `if`, as in RAZ_Muh_Taz's answer, is usually clearer.

Finally, to get an `else` to be the `else` for all `if`s, you need to use `else if`:

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else if (b) {
    ...
} else if (c) {
    ...
} else {
    // do this if all the above are false
    ..
}
```

When `return` statements are involved, `else` can often be omitted, though it's debatable whether you should, and I recommend it only with very structured situations that are beyond the scope of this question.  Best to start out always adding the `else` if conditions are mutually exclusive, and learn rules for omitting `else` later.

Answer (score 2):

Your if checks are equivalent to if true && if true then return isPath, therefore you can use an AND to concatenate the pairs of if's into a single if check. Then if the move is never valid you will return false since the given data didn't satisfy any of the if conditions.

```
if (row+1>0 && row+1<mat.length && nextVal==mat[row+1][clmn])
    return isPath (mat, val+1, row+1, clmn);

if (row-1>0 && row-1<mat.length && nextVal==mat[row-1][clmn])
    return isPath (mat, val+1, row-1, clmn);

if (clmn+1>0 && clmn+1<mat.length && nextVal==mat[row][clmn+1])
    return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn+1);

if (clmn-1>0 && clmn-1<mat.length && nextVal==mat[row][clmn-1])
    return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn-1);

return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you expected but there is a much tidier way to do this. Something like this would be much clearer to understand and edit.

```
static final int[][] moves = {
        // Row, column delta
        {1, 0},
        {-1, 0},
        {0, 1},
        {0, -1},
};

boolean moves(int[][] mat, int row, int col, int val, int nextVal) {
    for (int[] move : moves) {
        int newRow = row + move[0];
        int newCol = col + move[1];
        // On mat?
        if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < mat.length && newCol >= 0 && newCol < mat[newRow].length) {
            if (nextVal == mat[newRow][newCol]) {
                return isPath(mat, val + 1, newRow, newCol);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

NOTE: I have changed your `> 0` to `>= 0` assuming that is what you meant to use.

Comment: That's how I would have coded it.  Nitpick: I wouldn't have used the same identifier for a function and a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
    ...

```
if (row-1>0 && row-1<mat.length) { //valid move up
    if (nextVal==mat[row-1][clmn]) {
        return isPath (mat, val+1, row-1, clmn);
    }
}

if (clmn+1>0 && clmn+1<mat.length) { //valid move right
    if (nextVal==mat[row][clmn+1]) {
        return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn+1);
    }
}

if (clmn-1>0 && clmn-1<mat.length) { //valid move left
    if (nextVal==mat[row][clmn-1]) {
        return isPath (mat, val+1, row, clmn-1);
    }
}
return false;
```